the .env file and the associated commits from your Git history
how do I remove my .env file from my git repository history
I tried fixing it but still getting error
so I want remove the .env file and the associated commits from your Git history so that I can push my code to my github

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+history

git filter-repo --invert-paths --path .env
